# How to access to BuildConfig.grooy at runtime in grails 2.3.2

Tags: grails

In one of my app service, I need to access to some of the dependencies version I got compile, but I cannot find a way to access to the dependencies at runtime.

> BuildConfig.groovy

```
 dependencies {
        runtime 'com.oracle:ojdbc14:10.2.0.2.0'
        runtime 'com.google.guava:guava:11.0.1'
        runtime 'com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.2.2'
        runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.1'
 }
```

I need to access any dependecies version...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to get runtime dependencies, although it will return you all runtime dependencies, including those that were not explicitly defined by you.

```
BuildSettingsHolder.getSettings().runtimeDependencies.collect { it.name }
```

This will return you a list of names of all runtime dependencies, e.g.:

[image]

You can find dependencies you are interested in and extract their versions from String. I hope it helps you solving your problem.

Comment: I have to do regex to get the version, but it worked! Thanks

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I could help you :)